# Confluence Insert (better Insert Jira Issue) Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, confluence

What's the keyboard shortcut in Atlassian Confluence to activate the 'menu bar'?

Better still - what's the keyboard shortcut to activate the 'Insert' option on the menu?

Better still - what's the keyboard shortcut to activate the 'Insert Jira Issue/Filter' option on the Insert menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert a JIRA issue. (Opens the Insert JIRA Issue dialog.): `Ctrl+Shift+J`

Look at [Keyboard Shortcuts in Atlassian documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf57/keyboard-shortcuts-701434627.html).

Comment: I already checked https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf58/keyboard-shortcuts-771891833.html
Also the shortuts popup 9General, Editor, Editor Autoformatting) - I guess it's too convenient to put all shortcuts in one place accessible from the page/google.
But thank you for the answer.